# Change the color of a horizontal header in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I only want to change the color of the vertical header. Couldn't do anything with the stylesheet feature and all the solutions online are only for QTableView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("color: red");
    tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setStyleSheet("color: red");
```

Comment: Woops, I meant the column itself. How to edit the column itself, not the column's header.

Comment: Please be more precise. Do you want to color some specific cells of the table? Please check your question. It clearly states that you try to color the header.

Comment: If you like to color the background of the headerView:
tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color:blue }");